# Declaring an enum as a class member

Tags: c#, enums

Is there any mechanism in C# that allows one to define and declare an Enum variable in the same line like so:

```
public class ClassWithEnumMember
{
    public Enum Type { TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE3 } = TYPE1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, newlines are whitespace, thus can be collapsed into a single space. But **why** would you want such a thing?

Comment: I am not interested in newlines/spaces ... I am interested in that sort of grammar.

Comment: The question still remains. **Why**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simplest answer is no. Why not just make it two lines?

Comment: I was looking for a solution similar to declaring structs in C without typedef-ing them first.

Comment: "I can do this in C" is often a reason *not* to allow it in my language.

Comment: @Jay Bazuzi, good point. C# is excellent in preventing bad design ideas.

Answer (score 6):

```
public enum Foo { Bar, Baz }; public Foo myField = Foo.Bar;
```

All neatly on one line!

Comment: While I suspect the poster meant one statement when saying one line, I like this solution. You get an up vote.

Comment: I know what the poster meant. However I don't see why he'd want to do what he's trying to do.

Comment: Indeed. Hence the answer that I gave.